# How to sort when Integers are stored as Strings in DB using Pageable in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting

I'm been looking and tried various things to get the timeStamp to be sorted from lowest number to highest. I am using postgres and spring boot 3.2.2. The issue I am running into is the `startTimestamp` is stored in the database as String which I think is why the default sorting isn't working correct. I've also tried `Order.asc("startTimeStamp")` but postgres also sends a similar response.

This is my entity

```
public class YoutubeVideo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID Id;
    private String videoId;
    private String startTimeStamp;
    private String fullYouTubeUrl;
```

I have this function in my services that pulls the data from JpaRepository

```
 public Page<YoutubeVideoDto> findAllByYtVideoId(Integer pageNum, String videoId) {
                Page<YoutubeVideo> dbResponse = youtubeVideoRepository
                                .findAllByYtVideoId(PageRequest.of(pageNum, NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_PAGE, Sort.by("startTimeStamp").ascending()), videoId);
                                                                

                return dbResponse.map(this::mapYoutubeVideoDto);

        };
```

JPA Repository

```
public interface YoutubeVideoRepository extends JpaRepository<YoutubeVideo, UUID> {

    Page<YoutubeVideo> findAllByYtVideoId(Pageable pageable, String videoId);

}
```

I tried using the Sort.by("startTimeStamp").ascending but this is what I get when I request the API.

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "videoId": "videoIdHere",
            "startTimeStamp": "938",
            "fullYouTubeUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoIdHere&t=938",
            "id": "1423cb48-2bb4-42e3-a6a9-78b5b5995198"
        },
        {
            "videoId": "videoIdHere",
            "startTimeStamp": "620",
            "fullYouTubeUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoIdHere&t=620",
            "id": "d97ccc9e-5aed-47ae-a137-9ab2033b437e"
        },
        {
            "videoId": "videoIdHere",
            "startTimeStamp": "6023",
            "fullYouTubeUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoIdHere&t=6023",
            "id": "73517417-6d62-4511-9e96-68a0232d6999"
        },
        {
            "videoId": "videoIdHere",
            "startTimeStamp": "5788",
            "fullYouTubeUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoIdHere&t=5788",
            "id": "69960697-6162-4214-9f2f-b3f787f86989"
        },
        {
            "videoId": "videoIdHere",
            "startTimeStamp": "5460",
            "fullYouTubeUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoIdHere&t=5460",
            "id": "f7446385-4802-4666-8021-ed75de826a5f"
        },
        {
            "videoId": "videoIdHere",
            "startTimeStamp": "451",
            "fullYouTubeUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoIdHere&t=451",
            "id": "70ed415f-23f8-4ea3-be1a-4b6bfeb83ce0"
        },
        {
            "videoId": "videoIdHere",
            "startTimeStamp": "3979",
            "fullYouTubeUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoIdHere&t=3979",
            "id": "51634c42-503f-4c49-9d5e-b4e3bebc3861"
        },
        {
            "videoId": "videoIdHere",
            "startTimeStamp": "3679",
            "fullYouTubeUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoIdHere&t=3679",
            "id": "e13419be-ed68-4995-9212-65e6428f613a"
        },
        {
            "videoId": "videoIdHere",
            "startTimeStamp": "3421",
            "fullYouTubeUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoIdHere&t=3421",
            "id": "6826b818-73ac-4410-9a61-cafa38c46f92"
        },
        {
            "videoId": "videoIdHere",
            "startTimeStamp": "3126",
            "fullYouTubeUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoIdHere&t=3126",
            "id": "359a55e9-e2e1-4300-b576-4613b70b2a93"
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "sort": {
            "sorted": true,
            "unsorted": false,
            "empty": false
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "totalPages": 2,
    "totalElements": 15,
    "last": false,
    "first": true,
    "size": 10,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false,
        "empty": false
    },
    "numberOfElements": 10,
    "empty": false
}
```

The startTimeStamp isn't sequential from lowest to highest.

I've looked around the web and on here also stackoverflow and can't find exactly what I am looking for. I suspect I need to convert the `startTimestamp` as a Integer and then use the default sorter? I guess a custom Sorter needs to be implemented? or does anyone have another solution that I am overseeing.

Thank you.

Comment: You can convert to Timestamp using : Timestamp(long time).

Comment: right, integer or timestamp would work, the startTimestamp will never exceed the max integer value but I suppose timestamp would be more appropriate, but where would I do that conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because timestamp is stored as string and sorting will happen lexicographically and not numerically. If your only storing integers in this field I would recommend changing the type to Integer.

However, if it is not possible to change the type of this field you can write a custom query which will covert timestamp into an integer for sorting purposes:

```
@Query("SELECT v FROM YoutubeVideo v WHERE v.videoId = :videoId ORDER BY CAST(v.startTimeStamp AS int) ASC")
Page<YoutubeVideo> findByVideoIdSortedByStartTimeStamp(String videoId, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Yep. that did it. Thank you, I knew some type of casting is required from string to integer for the sort to work correctly, so glad it's done at the database level also. I left the videoTimeStamp field as a string because older type youtube videos consisted of m:s instead of a seconds time stamp its 13m45s but as of late all the new videos are in seconds. what I'll end up doing is migrating all the time stamp as a integer value and converting the older youtube time stamps also to a consistent data type Thanks again.